# pandas groupby then apply giving field name None

Tags: python, pandas

I have below code

```
data = (data
     .sort_values(by=['x','y'])
        .groupby(["x","y"], as_index=False)
        .apply(get_val)
        #.reset_index(name='rows')
    )
```

The get_val field name None

When I add

.reset_index(name='z')

Give an error

> reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

I have data like

```
 x   y rows
   a 1500.0    A
   a 1500.0    B
   a 1500.0    C
   b  700.0    C
   b 1500.0    D
   b  700.0    D
   b 1500.0    E
   c  700.0    E
   c 1500.0    F
   c  700.0    F
```

Any help
Thanks

Comment: I fixed this with lambda function with agg

Answer (score 0):

It is expected, because using [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - there is no parameter `name` - only in [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html).

If specify column after `groupby` and remove `as_index=False` it should working, because ouput is `Series`:

```
def get_val(x):
    return x.sum() + 1

data = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,1,2,0,0], 'y':[2,2,4,7,1,1], 'col':range(6)})
print (data)
   x  y  col
0  1  2    0
1  1  2    1
2  1  4    2
3  2  7    3
4  0  1    4
5  0  1    5

#groupby sorting by x, y by default, so removed
data = (data.groupby(["x","y"])['col']
            .apply(get_val)
            .reset_index(name='rows')
        )
print (data)
   x  y  rows
0  0  1    10
1  1  2     2
2  1  4     3
3  2  7     4
```

Comment: 'Column not found: cols'

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam - It seems in your data is no column `col`. Can you add some data sample to question?

Comment: When I give the column name which is there in dataframe it says KeyError: 'rows', rows is there

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam - Hard debug code without your data and your function. So I create some sample and sample function for testing - working well. If function is different, can you add to question for find problem?

Comment: sample data updated

Comment: the error was some other place.. but now I am getting multiple values for cols inside function

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam - Can you add function to question? thank you.